# How to obtain the JSON data as nil when saving in swift3?

Tags: json, swift3

**Code:**

```
var json: AnyObject?
do {
    json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:Any] as AnyObject?
    let UserID = json?["UserID"] as? [String:AnyObject]
    print(UserID) //printing nil

}
catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the root object of the JSON is a dictionary and the value for `userID` a string it might be

```
do {
    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String:Any] {
        if let userID = json["UserID"] as? String { // or as? Int if the user id is an integer
           print(userID)
        }
    }
}
catch {
    print(error)
}
```

`.allowFragments` is nonsense if the root object is supposed to be a collection type.